# Replication and Default Trace performance issues

Tags: sql-server-2005, replication, trace

After setting up a replication on my server (SQL2005) I have noticed that default system trace log is full of replication entries which cause a performance issue.

As default trace always logs any DBCC SPs and you cannot modify this behaviour we ended up with something like the following:

```
16  2011-05-18 22:45:40.137 dbcc addinstance ("SQL Replication Logreader", @agent_name)          
17  2011-05-18 22:45:40.137 dbcc incrementinstance ("SQL Replication Logreader", "Logreader:Delivered Trans/sec", @agent_name, @latest_delivered_transactions)          
18  2011-05-18 22:45:40.137 dbcc incrementinstance ("SQL Replication Logreader", "Logreader:Delivered Cmds/sec", @agent_name, @latest_delivered_commands)          
19  2011-05-18 22:45:40.137 dbcc setinstance ("SQL Replication Logreader", "Logreader:Delivery Latency", @agent_name, @delivery_latency)      
20  2011-05-18 22:45:45.137 dbcc addinstance ("SQL Replication Logreader", @agent_name)          
21  2011-05-18 22:45:45.137 dbcc incrementinstance ("SQL Replication Logreader", "Logreader:Delivered Trans/sec", @agent_name, @latest_delivered_transactions)          
22  2011-05-18 22:45:45.137 dbcc incrementinstance ("SQL Replication Logreader", "Logreader:Delivered Cmds/sec", @agent_name, @latest_delivered_commands)          
23  2011-05-18 22:45:45.137 dbcc setinstance ("SQL Replication Logreader", "Logreader:Delivery Latency", @agent_name, @delivery_latency)
```

Another problem is the location of the trace file. It is stored in the LOG directory for the SQL Server instance (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG) and 
in my case the C drive is not as much IO efficient as dedicated D partition which is the high performance array (RAID 10).

Should I disable the default trace on my server? 
Alternatively, What are the best practices in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't change the default trace. I've had a poke around on the interwebs and I see no information to the contrary.

You can disable it and roll your own of course.

Some [more info](http://blogs.technet.com/b/beatrice/archive/2008/04/29/sql-server-default-trace.aspx)

It'd be nice to have some Trace flag to control what the default trace does, perhaps. There isn't any [MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/SearchResults.aspx?SearchQuery=%2526quot%253bdefault%2btrace%2526quot%253b) article... yet ;-)

Comment: Yes, that's correct, you cannot change the default trace. I am quite surprised there isn't any place, like an advanced config, where you can set additional filters or at leasts specify a log file path. I might disable the default trace and add my own one. I am not going to accept your answer yet. Thanks for the suggestion.